# PL/SQL - LAST_VALUE return more than one row?

Tags: plsql, row

I am doing an school assigment where I need to get the last value of "code" so I can then insert next row with this code incremented. I tried to pull it out this way.

```
DECLARE

   v_last_code f_shifts.code%TYPE;

BEGIN

   SELECT LAST_VALUE(code) OVER (ORDER BY code)
   INTO v_last_code
   FROM f_shifts;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last value is: ' || v_last_code);

END;
```

However I get `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than one requested number of rows`
and I have no idea why and how can a last_value be more than one row

Thanks !

Comment: You have no `where` clause...

Comment: Okay, I am not so familiar with PLSQL yet. Why would I need a where clause? I just want the last value in that column. How would I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Because `last_value()` is an analytic function not an aggregate like `count(*)`. This means that you will return the last value for every row in the table. `count(*)` can also be an analytic function but I don't want to confuse things too much...

Comment: last value for every row, that doesnt sound right :-D, you mean column-wise? .. So, ..what do I need, WHERE code = LAST_VALUE(code)? IDK

Comment: No, if you only want the last value maybe you're looking for `max()`? Have you run this outside PL/SQL to see what results get returned.

Comment: Yes, that could work but I wanted explicitly the last_value, okay thanks

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'last value'?

Comment: the values in column "code" that was inserted in the latest insert

Comment: And how would you determine what the "latest insert" was?  AFAIK Oracle doesn't supply a way to know this - there would need to be something in your table to indicate that a particular row was the "last one inserted".

Comment: The point is that the code is PK, however they stupidly didnt setup sequence on it and I am not suppose to do that ..so I figured this out with WHERE COUNT(code) = ROWNUM, to get the latest value, increment it and use it in the insert

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested table like this.

```
DECLARE
   v_last_code f_shifts.code%TYPE;
   TYPE t_tbl IS TABLE OF f_shifts.code%TYPE;
      -- Above line creates the nested table type of the required type.
   v_tbl T_TBL;
      -- Above line creates the nested table variable.
BEGIN

   SELECT code
   BULK COLLECT INTO v_tbl -- collects all the values, ordered, into the nested table
   FROM f_shifts
   ORDER BY code;

   v_last_code = v_tbl(v_tbl.LAST); -- gets the last values and puts into the variable

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last value is: ' || v_last_code);

END;
/
```